# my career path in design

Tags: designers

Do you need a graphic design degree to work for a agency or company? I've researched many answers towards this question and what I found, it basically comes down to your portfolio. I don't want to do freelance and want to work for a company or agency. What are the steps? How can I be a successful graphic designer without a degree?

Answer (score 0):

Companies tend to look for both a education in design and good portfolio.

If your portfolio is solid and demonstrates what a company is looking for then you can absolutely get a job without study but on the merit of your portfolio alone. Typically freelance is how you build your portfolio though.

A internships might be possible but without a education in design or work to show most agencies will see you as too big of a gamble to employ even as a intern.